# How can I resolve "sun.security.x509" is not visible when migrating from 1.8 to openJDK11?

Tags: java, ant, java-11, openjdk-11

I am migrating Java 1.8 to OpenJDK 11. Getting some dependency errors.

1. "sun.security.x509" is not visible.
2. BASE64Encoder error

How can I resolve these? I am using Apache Ant for build.

Comment: Have a look at [why you should not use `sun` packages directly](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html)

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell you how to address the first problem since you haven't shown us the code where you are using classes in the `sun.security.x509` package.  A possible workaround *might* be to use `--add-exports` and/or `--add-opens` as described in this blog post:

- [All You Need To Know For Migrating To Java 11](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/)

However, that work-around is liable to stop working in the future.  The solution would be to find a way to avoid depending on those classes.

The second problem can be used by rewriting your code to use the `java.util.Base64` class ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)) that was introduced in Java 8.

---

> I am using Apache Ant for build.

That is not directly relevant.  The root cause of the problem is in the code you are building not the build tool you are using.